# Feather MO: How would I change my code to have my txt file data be in columns rather than be staggered?

Tags: gps

First of all, I am using the Feather MO Adalogger from Adafruit with the Ultimate GPS Feather hat to collect some GPS data: time stamp (millisec), GPS Coordinates (latitude & longitude), speed (knots), and altitude (meters). The GPS data is stored on a micro SD card and I have the GPS portion of the code working. The data I want is being stored on the micro SD card. My only problem is that I can't get the data to be appropriately put in columns under their respective "headers". I used .print("\t") after each data type in attempt to tab the data into columns. This worked for the "headers" but not for the data itself. Screenshots and code are below. Thanks in advance!

My txt file: Headers

[image: Headers in my txt file]

My text file: working GPS data
[image: Data in my txt file]

Code for Headers
[image: headers code]

Code for data
[image: data code]

Comment: Don't post sketch images; post the sketch itself, so others can copy-paste them for testing.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of code, not just snippets. Minimal means you've stripped away irrelevant stuff, just leaving what's needed to show the problem. Complete means all the library names are shown, all the variable declarations, and all the function definitions – so people don't have to waste time guessing what you did or what you meant. Verifiable means it can be compiled and tested, allowing other people to test their theories about the problem

Comment: The tab '\t' has no fixed number of positions. It can be every 2 or every 8 or anything else. You can try to fill up with spaces. For example the sprintf function can do that. Are you sure you want to show the text file nicely formatted under the headers? It is more common to use the text file as data for visualization tools.

Comment: @Jot  I just want my data to be easily copy/pasted into a data manipulation/graphing program like excel or matlab. Any suggestions on how to do that? I copied the data the way it is but it pastes awkwardly into excel. Thanks btw

Comment: @user52619 And we want easily copy/pasteable code for testing.

Comment: Since I don't like the tab character, I would use only ", " between the numbers with a println() at the end as @jose-can-u-c wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `println()`s to `print()`s. Put one `println()` at the end of the list of data prints.  You want each row of data to not take up more than one line in the text file. A `println()` starts a new row after printing.

Also, you’ll want to open the text file in a tabular program like Excel or similar. A plain text editor likely won’t utilize tab characters in the way you like.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That worked perfectly just how I wanted! (: